# Correlation energy - is it the difference between the Hartree-Fock energy and exact energy, or Hartree-Fock PE and exact PE?

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-physics, quantum-chemistry

For some reason I can't find anything stating it either way explicitly. What I'm talking about is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_correlation). Is this difference referring to potential energies or just energies in general? I assume it's potential energies since the kinetic energies would be temperature-dependent, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Firstly, please not confuse with atomic behavior and electronic behavior. As for electronic energy, Hamiltonian includes K and P. So, electronic energy is the total energy of electron. As for temperature, it affect motion of atoms but as to electron, it will change the distribution of electron on different electronic states through the Dirac-Fermi distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correlation energy is generally defined as the difference between the true total energy and the Hartree-Fock limit.

There are mainly two reasons for HF not being exact. Firstly, it approximates the many-body wavefunction as a single Slater determinant, while the exact result must be taken as a combination of many Slater determinants. This leads to a lowering of the total energy and is referred to as nondynamical correlation. Secondly, HF assumes that each electron only interacts with an average charge distribution due to all other electrons, while in reality electrons are point particles constantly in motion, trying to avoid each other's paths. It is the instantaneous Coulomb repulsion that affects their kinetic energies and is referred to as dynamical correlation. So to answer your question, yes, the kinetic energy contribution is included and can be quite important sometimes.

Note that HF actually already includes some correlation: namely that required by the antisymmetry principle, which is a static effect acting only between parallel spin electrons. Generally, however, when we say correlation we mean the other parts as described above. These act between both parallel and antiparallel spin electrons.

Explicitly, in terms of 1- and 2-particle density matrices, the exchange-correlation energy can be written as
$$ E_{xc}[n] = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{n(\mathbf r,\mathbf r';\mathbf r,\mathbf r') - n(\mathbf r,\mathbf r)n(\mathbf r,'\mathbf r')}{|\mathbf r - \mathbf r'|} \mathrm d\mathbf r\mathrm d\mathbf r',$$
where
$$n(\mathbf r,\mathbf r) = n(\mathbf r),$$
$$n(\mathbf r,\mathbf r';\mathbf r,\mathbf r') = \langle \Psi | \hat\psi^\dagger(\mathbf r) \hat\psi^\dagger(\mathbf r') \hat\psi(\mathbf r') \hat\psi(\mathbf r) |\Psi \rangle.$$
(Taken from the seminal paper of Hohenberg and Kohn.) The difference between $E_{xc}$ and the HF exchange energy would give you the correlation energy.

Answer (score 1):

It's thirty-five (!) years since I last did an HF/SCF calculation, but in those days our code worked by minimising the energy:

$$ E_{HF} = \langle \Psi_{HF} | H | \Psi_{HF} \rangle $$

where $\Psi_{HF}$ is the approximate wavefunction expressed as a sum of some convenient basis set of functions.

Once you'd done the HF/SCF calculation you'd do a CI calculation, and that would give you a new wavefunction and energy:

$$ E_{CI} = \langle \Psi_{CI} | H | \Psi_{CI} \rangle $$

The electron correlation energy is $E_{HF} - E_{CI}$ in the limit of doing a perfect calculation i.e. using an infinite basis set. Obviously you'd only ever be able to approximate the correlation energy.

Comment: Yes, but EHF and ECI refer to total energies, then? Some places I read seemed to suggest that they meant potential energy. I don't really understand why the total energy would be important as that is temperature dependent [because of kinetic part] is it not?

Comment: @user1126849: Yes, it does refer to the difference in total energy. However bear in mind that the total energies have a global gauge symmetry so what exactly they mean is debatable. When we're doing an HF/SCF calculation we're almost always calculating the difference between two systems e.g. comparing the energy of a molecule with the energy of isolated atoms. We're normally also calculating the energy at absolute zero so no rotational or vibrational modes are excited.